# Should I wrap socket.io in a try/catch?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, try-catch

I have a node.js server that uses socket.io and I'm wondering if it would be smart, stupid, or just plain wouldn't work if wrapped my entire  `io.on('connection',` (I only have one namespace) callback in a try-catch so that if a client connects and maliciously sends data through the sockets in a way I havent defended against yet it won't crash my entire server

Comment: NodeJS boasts pretty decent error handling -- a try/catch block is not required since every callback function can chain an error function

Comment: what do you mean "chain an error function"?

Comment: https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors